# Broken PUT request with jquery/python GAE

Tags: jquery, python, http, google-app-engine

I'm using jQuery's AJAX function, like so:

```
$.ajax ({ "url" : "/note",
         "async" : true,
         "type" : "POST",
         "data" : {"id" : id, "content" : el.value}
       });
```

On the backend (Python Google App Engine, currently using webapp.RequestHandler), PUT requests are handled by the same function that handles POST requests, like so:

```
class uNote(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        logging.critical("ID: " + self.request.get('id'))
        note = stickynote.db.get( self.request.get('id') )
        if note:
            content = self.request.get( 'content' )
            if content:
                note.content = content
            else:
                note.x = int(self.request.get('x'))
                note.y = int(self.request.get('y'))
                note.z = int(self.request.get('z'))
            note.put()
            self.response.out.write ( "true" );
        else:
            self.response.out.write ("no id found")

def put(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        logging.critical("ID: " + self.request.get('id'))
        note = stickynote.db.get( self.request.get('id') )
        if note:
            content = self.request.get( 'content' )
            if content:
                note.content = content
            else:
                note.x = int(self.request.get('x'))
                note.y = int(self.request.get('y'))
                note.z = int(self.request.get('z'))
            note.put()
            self.response.out.write ( "true" );
        else:
            self.response.out.write ("no id found")
```

If I make a POST request everything works. If I change it to a PUT request (by changing type of the AJAX call), nothing works. If I check the logs for GAE, I see:

```
BadKeyError: Invalid string key .
```

This is the result of me logging the ID for each call:

```
ID: ahFkZXZ-YXp2ZC13ZWJub3Rlc3ItCxIKU3RpY2t5Tm90ZSIQdGVzdEBleGFtcGxlLmNvbQwLEgdzbk1vZGVsGAIM (from the POST call)
ID: (from the PUT call)
```

So clearly it's not passing the ID properly for PUT calls, which is why the datastore is giving me a BadKeyError. I'm not sure if this is a problem on jQuery's side, or if it's from GAE's side, though, and I have no idea what's going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since there's clearly an issue on the server end, you need to show us the code you're running on the server side if we're to be of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.request.POST`, and hence `self.request.get()` [don't return form data for PUT requests](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/lib/webob/webob/__init__.py#834) (or any non-POST requests). While it's not usual to submit form data using a PUT request (more commonly, you're submitting something as the body of the request), it's certainly a little odd that they're deliberately disabling it here.

If you want to access the data, you'll need to decode it from the body yourself, either using `urlparse.parse_qs(self.request.body)`, or [like this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/lib/webob/webob/__init__.py#865).

Another option would be to modify your API so you're not using form data - for instance, by making the ID part of the URL, and send the content as the raw body of the PUT request.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

I'm planning on making the ID part of the URL, I was just trying to convert it from POST to PUT a step at a time to make sure everything was working right. I'm still going to need do this conversion, anyway, since the body is going to be a json object, not a form object.

Comment: @Alex With a JSON object, though, the decoding is the same either way - `simplejson.loads(self.request.body)` - which ought to make your life easier.